# Preencher List com retorno de sql

Tags: c#, sql

bom dia

Como faço para preencher uma Lista com um retorno de um sql?

O que eu tentei fazer com certeza vai me dar um outofrange exception

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string query = "select * from pedidos_distribuidos";
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list[0] = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        //using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        //{
        //    cmd.Connection = con;
        //    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        //    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        //    {
        //        sda.Fill(dt);
        //        pedidos = sda.A ;
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

**O que eu estou fazendo**

```
var list = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            {
                list = con.Query<string>("select * from pedidos_distribuidos" ).ToString() ;

            }


            int total = list.Count();
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parametrosPaginacao.SearchPhrase))
            {
                //  areaClientes = areaClientes.Where("Area.Contains(@0) OR DescricaoGAreaCliente(@0)", parametrosPaginacao.SearchPhrase);
                list = list.Where("Protocolo.Contains(@0)", parametrosPaginacao.SearchPhrase).ToString();
            }

            var pedidosPaginados = list.OrderBy(parametrosPaginacao.CampoOrdenado).Skip((parametrosPaginacao.Current - 1) * parametrosPaginacao.RowCount).Take(parametrosPaginacao.RowCount);

            //int total = 0;
            DadosFiltrados dadosFiltrados = new DadosFiltrados(parametrosPaginacao)
            {
                rows = pedidosPaginados.ToList(),
                total = total
            };
            return dadosFiltrados;

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Preciso que retorne o resultado do select

Comment: seria só fazer isso: `list.Add(reader[0].ToString());` mas, fica muito mais fácil se usar o dapper como o AR colocou

Comment: Acontece que esse drapper está me retornando dado 12 vezes mais do que o normal @RovannLinhalis

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi

Comment: @RovannLinhalis coloquei lá

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80450/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-rovann-linhalis).

Comment: Mesmo assim quando eu coloco   list = con.Query<string>("select Protocolo from pedidos_distribuidos" ).ToString(); ele me retorna 48

Comment: Pelo amor de deus gabrielfalieri, você precisa estudar os conceitos da linguagem antes mano. 

list = con.Query<string>("select * from pedidos_distribuidos" ).ToString() ;

Você tem mais resultados porque dá um select * from (que deveria retornar um objeto e não string) e ainda me dá um list.ToString...

Comment: @GustavoSantos seja um pouco mais educado por favor?

Comment: Não faltei com o respeito, mas é claro que você não conhece a linguagem e está fazendo algo fora do que você conhece, é uma dica, estudar a linguagem antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas complementando a resposta, e explicando melhor o problema relatado no chat:

Crie uma classe para seus resultados:

```
public class PedidosDistribuidos
{
    public string Protocolo {get;set;}
    public DateTime DataProtocolo {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
}
```

Depois execute a Query, retornando a lista tipada:

```
List<PedidosDistribuidos> list;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    list = con.Query<PedidosDistribuidos>("select protocolo, data_protocolo, descricao from pedidos_distribuidos").ToList();

}
```

> Repare que não tem .ToString no final da execução da query; A lista é declarada antes do bloco using (pois você quer usa-la depois);

Comment: @gabrielfalieri ainda há problemas graves na sua abordagem, você deveria filtrar, paginar e ordenar direto na sua consulta. hoje você está trazendo toda a tabela para a memoria, lhe garanto que esta é uma das maneiras mais praticas para se cometer suicídio.

Answer (score 4):

Para que reinventar a roda? utilize o [`Dapper`](https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/).:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
{
    var list = con.Query<string>("select coluna from pedidos_distribuidos");
}
```

Comment: Mesquista, havia me esquecido disso, até exclui minha resposta

Comment: Primeiro, quem é esse connection, o connectionString?

Segundo, está dando erro de "string does not contain a definition for query"

Comment: @gabrielfalieri vi que editou a resposta, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Não, continua dando erro

Comment: você declarou list como uma string.: `var list = "";`
vendo o seu código agora, você tem bem mais problemas do que o retorno da consulta.